# addAction to IntentFilter to handle Phone State Change

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager, android-broadcastreceiver, phone-state-listener

I want to listen to an incoming call.

I know that you have to give permissions inside AndroidManifest and set the receiver with

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

and

```
<receiver ... 
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />...
```

But, in my project, I have the receiver set by code, with

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction( ... );
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
```

Where inside `addAction` I put `TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED`

and I create the BroadcastReceiver with

```
private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { ...
```

Then, inside it, I take the action from the intent with `String action = intent.getAction();` and I check which action is it.
It works great for Bluetooth

```
filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
```

And

```
switch (action) {
    case BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED: ...
```

But it does not checks `TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED`.

**So, my questions are:**

How do you set the action (`addAction()`) to listen to state changes?

Is `TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` not right?

If I would give up and set the receiver inside AndroiManifest, how would I set the filters for Bluetooth? I'm using

```
BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND
BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED
BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED
```

Comment: It is likely that your app doesn't have the required permission, even though you have specified it in the manifest. In later versions of Android you actually have to check if your app has the required permission and if it doesn't, request the permission from the user. Have you checked this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First register reciever in your activity

```
this.registerReceiver(this.broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED));
```

and this is the broadcastReceiver:

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        if (state == null) {

            //Outgoing call
            String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            Log.e("tag", "Outgoing number : " + number);

        } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {

            Log.e("tag", "EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK");

        } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {

            Log.e("tag", "EXTRA_STATE_IDLE");

        } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

            //Incoming call
            String number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Log.e("tag", "Incoming number : " + number);

        } else
            Log.e("tag", "none");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Create this object in `onCreate()` method:

```
tMg =(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

listener = new PhoneStateListener{

    onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber){
         switch(state){
               case EXTRA_STATE_RINGING:
                   // phone is ringing
               break;
               case EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                  // phone is offhook
               break;
               case EXTRA_STATE_IDLE:
                 // phone is idle
               break;
         }
    }

}
```

in `onStart()` register your listener:

```
tMg.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

in `onStop()` unregister your listener:

```
tMg.listen(listener,  PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
```